# In what sense is std::disjunction short-circuiting at compile_time

Tags: c++, std, c++17, variadic-templates, if-constexpr

From the description on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction), I was under the impression that std::disjunction is designed to give me short-circuiting at compile-time, so that I can use it like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<nullptr_t null = nullptr>
constexpr bool does_not_compile() {
    static_assert(null != nullptr);
    return false;
}

void hello_world () {
    if constexpr (std::disjunction_v<std::true_type, std::bool_constant<does_not_compile()>>) {
        std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, this does not compile, std::disjunction does not short-circuit in the sense that the above static_assert doesn't trigger ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9784bc1092893919)).

But then it what sense is it short-circuiting? It can't be the usual behavior of || at run time, because the type of the std::disjunction has to be known at compile time, and it depends on its value.

Comment: Now by experimenting a bit more with static_assert and if constexpr, I observe very strange interactions between them. For example, an unreachable static_assert(false) produces an compilation error, but reformulating in a way so that the compiler doesn't know that it is false in every instantiation, then it compiles just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find an explanation right on the page you linked to:

> Disjunction is short-circuiting: if there is a template type argument `Bi` with `bool(Bi::value) != false`, then instantiating `disjunction<B1, ..., BN>::value` does not require the instantiation of `Bj::value` for j > i

The short-circuiting behavior concerns the `value` member of each parameter type, not the parameter type itself. You cannot instantiate a template without knowing it's paramters. And using `std::disjunction<…>` will generally require an instantiation. In your example

```
std::disjunction_v<std::true_type, std::bool_constant<does_not_compile()>>
```

the compiler still has to instantiate `std::bool_constant<does_not_compile()>` so that it knows what the whole `std::disjunction<…>` comes out to be (as you have noted yourself). What is guaranteed is that it won't instantiate `std::bool_constant<does_not_compile()>::value`…

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. I made another live demo to observe this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21b0f0cabb007b03 This compiles, and if you change std::true_type to std::false_type, then the static_assert triggers.

Comment: @x432ph yep, that's exactly it.